# Unity3d delay in while true loop not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, while-loop, infinite-loop, yield-return

I'm still working on the game and i ran into another problem, I'm trying to make an infinite loop which waits for a couple seconds every execute, i currently have:

---

StartScript.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using ProgressBar;

public class StartScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private ProgressBarBehaviour hunger;
    private ProgressBarBehaviour stamina;
    private ProgressRadialBehaviour health;
    private ProgressBarBehaviour thirst;

    public void OnGUI(){
        this.hunger = GameObject.Find("hungerBar").GetComponent<ProgressBarBehaviour>();
        this.stamina = GameObject.Find("staminaBar").GetComponent<ProgressBarBehaviour>();
        this.health = GameObject.Find("healthBar").GetComponent<ProgressRadialBehaviour>();
        this.thirst = GameObject.Find("thirstBar").GetComponent<ProgressBarBehaviour>();

        this.health.Value = 100f;
        this.stamina.Value = 100f;

        StartCoroutine ("runHunger");
    }

    bool addBar(ProgressBarBehaviour target, float percentage){
        Debug.Log (percentage);
        if ((target.Value + percentage) <= 100f) {
            target.IncrementValue (percentage);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool damageBar(ProgressBarBehaviour target, float percentage){
        if ((target.Value - percentage) >= 0f) {
            target.DecrementValue (percentage);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool addRadial(ProgressRadialBehaviour target, float percentage){
        if ((target.Value + percentage) <= 100f) {
            target.IncrementValue (percentage);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool damageRadial(ProgressRadialBehaviour target, float percentage){
        if ((target.Value - percentage) >= 0f) {
            target.DecrementValue (percentage);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    IEnumerator runHunger(){
        while (true) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
            /*if (!this.addBar(this.hunger,5f)) {
                this.damageRadial(this.health,3f);
            }*/
            Debug.Log("Time: "+Time.time);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator runHealth(){
        while (true) {

        }
    }
    /*
    IEnumerator runThirst(){
        while (true) {

            if (!this.thirst.Add (2)) {
                this.health.Damage(8);
            }

        }
    }*/
}
```

As you guys can see I'm trying to make a `while(true){}` loop with an `yield return new WaitForSeconds()`, the idea is that it runs the function in the loop every (in this test case) 10 seconds.

The first time executing works like a charm, it waits for 10 seconds, but after that it only waits for like 0.1 seconds and executes again.

---

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: ciao Giovanniu -- never, ever use "ongui" for any reason - it is removed from Unity!  Just use the ordinary UI.  It is absolutely easy, (1) click "add canvas" (select "scale to screen size" usually).  (2) click "add button".   (3) you are done .. go home to wife & wine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are too many wrong things I currently see in your code.

**This:**

```
IEnumerator runHealth(){
    while (true) {

    }
}
```

**Change it to**

```
IEnumerator runHealth(){
    while (true) {

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

**Also This**:

```
IEnumerator runThirst(){
    while (true) {

        if (!this.thirst.Add (2)) {
            this.health.Damage(8);
        }
    }           
}
```

**Change it to**

```
IEnumerator runThirst(){
    while (true) {

        if (!this.thirst.Add (2)) {
            this.health.Damage(8);
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

If you are gonna have `while(true)` in a coroutine, you must have yield return  something or it will **lock** your program. **Fix** these problems first. It is good to have it just before the closing bracket of the while loop.

I am sure you **did** this in **other** **scripts** too.
**Go** over the **rest** of other **scripts** and do the same thing. Put  `yield return null` **inside**  each **while loop** in each **coroutine** function.

**ANOTHER BIG MISTAKE**:
**Remove** every code from **OnGUI function** and put it in **Start** function like below. The code is being called too several times per frame and that will lead to **slow** down as you will be **creating** **many many** **coroutines** that **never** **stops** due to your **while loop** in the coroutine function.Putting it in the **Start** function will call it **once**.

```
void Start()
{
    this.hunger = GameObject.Find("hungerBar").GetComponent<ProgressBarBehaviour>();
    this.stamina = GameObject.Find("staminaBar").GetComponent<ProgressBarBehaviour>();
    this.health = GameObject.Find("healthBar").GetComponent<ProgressRadialBehaviour>();
    this.thirst = GameObject.Find("thirstBar").GetComponent<ProgressBarBehaviour>();

    this.health.Value = 100f;
    this.stamina.Value = 100f;

    StartCoroutine ("runHunger");
}
```

Comment: it currently is yield returning a new waitforseconds so its Always returning something, the only thing that is actually running is the hunger thing

Comment: No, I am talking about other functions with while(true). That is an infinite loop and therefore must return yield return null. The one with  yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f) is fine.

Comment: But the WHOLE problem is that the ones with the waitforseconds only wants once for that duration

Comment: I discovered another problem and edited my answer. Please fix all these.

Comment: np. and if you dont make modification in runHealth and runThirst, your game will freeze.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't sure if you were calling them from other classes. Good!

Answer (score 2):

Call the `StartCoroutine ("runHunger");`
somewhere other than in  OnGUI(). It will work then. Since everytime OnGUI is called it starts a new coroutine

Call the StartCoroutine in Start() or someplace else